# Prometheus - How to filter out stale metrics from range queries?

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, promql

On my Prometheus instance, I have set `storage.tsdb.retention.size` to `128GiB` and `storage.tsdb.retention.time` to `0s`, so Prometheus keeps the old data until the 128 GB limit is reached.

Now, I have some time series that haven't been updated anymore (i.e. are stale) for a long time. If I make a range query into the recent past where the stale metrics didn't exist anymore, then everything is fine.

For example, the PromQL query:

```
> metric{label1="foo"}[1d]
```

Returns:

```
...
metric{label1="foo"}  <value>@<timestamp>  # <== OK, fresh time series
```

However, if I make a range query reaching farther into the past when the stale metric was still updated, this stale time series is included in the result.

For example, the query:

```
> metric{label1="foo"}[60d]
```

Returns:

```
...
metric{label1="foo"}               <value>@<timestamp>  # <== OK, newest timestamp right now
...
metric{label1="foo",label2="bar"}  <value>@<timestamp>  # <== !! newest timestamp one month ago!
```

I don't want the second (stale) time series included in the result, I only want the data from first (fresh) time series reaching 60 days back.

Is there a way to achieve this with PromQL, i.e. filtering out stale time series from range queries?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: You could do sth like `metric{} and changes(metric{}[1h]) > 0`. That should filter out series that did not change within the last 1h. However, a change from `null` to a number is also counted, so it may not behave as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out currently absent time series by adding something like

```
and mymetric@end()
```

at the end of your query (respecting labels dropped from your query).

For example you can do this:

```
max_over_time(ALERTS[60m])and ALERTS@end()
```

or this:

```
count by(instance) (max_over_time(ALERTS[60m])) and on(instance) ALERTS@end()
```